# Proving closed curve on n-sphere is homotopic to constant curve

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-topology

I suppose that this would follow from n-sphere being simply connected, but is there an easier way to visualize how these would be homotopic? Obviously n>1.

Comment: Is your curve supposed to have no double points?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net not specified - I would assume no? If it makes it impossible then definitely no, because the homotopy in this case is possible.

Comment: Remove a point in your sphere and you will find yourself in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I don't know about easier, but there is a different viewpoint you might find enlightening: search for essential / inessential mappings and dimension theory.  Dimension can be characterized by the following: $X$ has dimension less than or equal to $n$ if and only if for each closed set $C \subset X$ and every continuous map $f:C \to S^n$, the map $f$ extends to a continuous map $F:X \to S^n$.   Here $X$ should be nice, e.g. separable metric space.  Take $X = D^2$ and $C$ its boundary circle.